# Mongoid::Contextual#each delegated to context.each, but context is nil

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I have a Sinatra application connecting to MongoDB via Mongoid. It was working fine until a point where I started getting a weird error that I can't find anywhere on stackoverflow or anywhere.

Note that the same code is deployed on Heroku and it works fine with the same database version Mongo 3.0.7, ruby version 2.0.0 which I tried locally as well as 2.2.3. I get the error when I run shotgun through the web and when running Rspec:

```
Bible::Book#get_book_id is case-insensitive
 Failure/Error: book[0]._id

 Module::DelegationError:
   Mongoid::Contextual#each delegated to context.each, but context is nil: #<Mongoid::Criteria
     selector: {"title"=>"genesis"}
     options:  {}
     class:    Bible::Book
     embedded: false>
 # /Users/issa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `rescue in each'
 # /Users/issa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `each'
 # /Users/issa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:554:in `entries'
 # /Users/issa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:554:in `method_missing'
 # ./app/bible/book.rb:52:in `get_book_id'
 # ./spec/bible/book_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # NoMethodError:
 #   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
 #   /Users/issa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/mongo-2.1.2/lib/mongo/cluster.rb:114:in `initialize'
```

My Rspec code:

```
RSpec.describe Bible::Book do

   describe "#get_book_id" do
      it "finds the id of genesis" do
          expect(Bible::Book.get_book_id 'genesis').to eq 1
      end
   end
end
```

The code implementation is this:

```
module Bible

   class Book

      include Mongoid::Document

      store_in collection: "bible_books"

      field :title, type: String
      field :testament, type: String
      ...

      def self.get_book_id book_title
        book = where(:title => book_title.downcase.strip)
        return unless book
        book[0]._id
      end
   end
end
```

My Gemfile has this part for MongoDB:

```
# MongoDB
...
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'bson'
```

It's really strange that I get this error only on my machine, and just started out of the blue. I am using OS X El Capitan. I can access the mongodb collection from command line without issues and can run the same equivalent query to get the result I want:

```
> use bible
switched to db bible
> db.bible_books.find({"title": "genesis"})
{ "_id" : 1, "title" : "genesis", "testament" : "old", "chapters" : 50, "doc_type" : "book", "canon_type" : "canonical", "canon_order" : 1, "full_name" : { "en" : "The book of Genesis", "ar" : "سفر التكوين" }, "short_name" : { "en" : "Genesis", "ar" : "التكوين" }, "abbr_name" : { "ar" : "تك", "en" : "Gen" } }
```

I tried other collections, other queries, other variations, and still get the same error. I reverted to an older code from github that worked for sure, still the same issue, so it's clear to me that there's nothing wrong in my code or configuration. I tried different ruby versions from 2.0.0 - 2.2.3, different mongoid versions from 4 - 5 ... again the same versions of code and installation work fine on Heroku, but not my machine :(

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error when wrong production configuration url was specified for mongoid: `uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>`

Comment: I had something pretty similar when I didn't have an environment variable set properly as well. It's a rather difficult to understand error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the source of your problem but I see a couple odd things in your `get_book_id` class method.

First of all, this will never leave `book.nil?`:

```
book = where(:title => book_title.downcase.strip)
```

That will leave you with a `Mongoid::Contextual` in `book`, the query may or may not find anything but `book` won't be `nil` in either case. That means that your:

```
return unless book
```

on the next line doesn't do anything useful. That also means that `book[0]` can be `nil` in here:

```
book[0]._id
```

You're also calling the `_id` method when you'd usually call `id`.

I think your method would be better off like this:

```
def self.get_book_id book_title
  book = find_by(:title => book_title.downcase.strip)
  return unless book
  book.id
end
```

`find_by(query)` is just a short way of saying `where(query).first` so `book = find_by(...)` will leave you with a `nil` in `book` if it can't find anything and a single `Bible::Book` in `book` if it can find something.

If you have ActiveSupport available, you could also say:

```
find_by(:title => book_title.downcase.strip).try(:id)
```

to hide the `nil` check. You could also throw in an `only` call to only pull the `_id` out of MongoDB:

```
book = only(:id).find_by(:title => book_title.downcase.strip)
return unless book
book.id

# or, if ActiveSupport is around, just this:
only(:id).find_by(:title => book_title.downcase.strip).try(:id)
```